# How to write logs to two different loggers?

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

Im able to create two logs using log4j2 and im able to write the log to a single log file. how to write logs to a two different loggers?

i modified the log4j2.xml file to have two loggers.

Any sample example?

Comment: Can you close this if the below answered your question?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of configuring multiple loggers, you may want to configure multiple appenders. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">
  <Appenders>
    <File name="MyFile" fileName="logs/app.log">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </File>
    <File name="Other" fileName="logs/other.log">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </File>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="MyFile" level="trace"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="Other" level="debug"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Point 1**

I guess you're asking to write one log into different destinations, ex. different files. As Remko has mentioned, you could configure different appenders to handle each of the log file.

As I don't have enough reputations for commenting Remko's answer, here're some of my additional examples:

If you use the level of DEBUG for your logs, calling `logger.debug("your message")` and configure your log4j2.xml like the below, you'll see "your message" logged in both file1.log and file2.log.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <File name="File1" fileName="logs/file1.log">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>"Add your pattern here"</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </File>
    <File name="File2" fileName="logs/file2.log">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>"Add your pattern here"</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </File>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="debug">
      <!--This will write the same log into both of the files -->
      <AppenderRef ref="File1" level="debug"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="File2" level="debug"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**Point 2**

we should notice that, in Remko's example, all logs go into Other will also be written into MyFile. See more in [Log4j2 Documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/architecture.html#Log%20Levels), example 6 for explaination. In short, as TRACE is a lower lever than DEBUG, all logs with DEBUG levels could be passed in TRACE and logged.

**Point 3**

Another possibility of writing into different destinations is through Appender Additivity.

> Each enabled logging request for a given logger will be forwarded to
>   all the apprenders in that Logger's LoggerConfig as well as the
>   Apprenders of the LoggerConfig's parents.